# First of two chained transitions in D3 gets interrupted and fails to run

Tags: d3.js, transition

I have a function that runs a two-part, chained transition using D3. For the initial run of the transition, I want the first part to execute quickly. In fact, I set a duration of 0ms.

So, I have something like:

```
t0 = selection.transition().duration(0)
```

I set the second part of the transition to run for longer, e.g.:

```
t0.transition().duration(2000)
```

My problem: when the first part of the transition has a duration of 0, it gets interrupted (presumably by the second part of the transition) and doesn't run.

Setting the duration of the first transition to something like 500ms fixes the problem.

What's going on here? Is it not possible to set different durations for each sub-transition?

Note: I realize I could just initialize the proper starting values without a transition, but seeing this behavior has me wondering if I'm not using chained transitions correctly.

EXAMPLE BELOW:

```js
var DAT=[];

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){DAT.push(i)}

var rects = d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect").data(DAT);
rects.enter().append("rect");
rects.attr({x:0,y:0,height:10,width:0,fill:"red",stroke:"none"});

var XPOS = 100;
var DURATION = 0; //first transition runs with a duration of 0

function GO(){
    var status0 = d3.select("#t0").text("NOT COMPLETE");
    var status1 = d3.select("#t1").text("NOT COMPLETE");
    var t0 = rects.transition().duration(DURATION).attr("x",XPOS)
        .each("end",function(d,i){
            if(i===9){status0.text("COMPLETE")}
        });
    t0.transition().duration(2000)
      .attr("y",function(d,i){return i*15})
      .attr("width",function(d,i){return Math.random()*300})
      .each("end",function(d,i){
          if(i===9){status1.text("COMPLETE")}
      });
}

GO();

d3.select("#button0").on("mousedown",function(){
    var node = d3.select("input").node();
    var dur = node.value;
    if(dur==="" || dur===null || typeof dur==="undefinded" || isNaN(dur)){
      dur = 0;
      node.value = dur;
    }
    XPOS = Math.random()*100 + 50;
    DURATION = dur; //set duration to 500
    GO(); //re-run transition
});

d3.select("#button1").on("mousedown",function(){
    XPOS = Math.random()*100 + 50;
    DURATION = 500; //set duration to 500
    GO(); //re-run transition
});

d3.select("input").on("mousedown",function(){d3.event.stopPropagation()})
```

```css
p, h1{font-family:arial,Helvetica,sans}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<h1>Example of problem with chained transitions</h1>
<p>When run with a duration of 0, the first transition (that shifts all bars right) is interrupted and does not run. The second part of the transition runs successfully</p>
<p>After changing the duration of the first transition to 500ms, both parts of the transition run successfully. Press "Redraw" buttons to demonstrate.</p>
<div id="button0" style="width:350px;height:auto;padding:5px 5px 15px 5px;border:1px solid red;border-radius:10px;fill:#ffffff;cursor:pointer; margin:0px;">
  <p style="text-align:center;pointer-events:none;color:red">Redraw with first transition duration of</p> 
  <input style="float:left;margin-left:34%;width:10%;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;" value=0 />
  <p style="float:left;color:red;margin:2px 0px 0px 5px;"> milliseconds</p>
  <div style="width:0px;clear:both;position:relative;"></div>
</div>
<div id="button1" style="width:350px;height:auto;padding:5px;border:1px solid red;border-radius:10px;fill:#ffffff;cursor:pointer; margin:0px;margin-top:5px;">
    <p style="text-align:center;pointer-events:none;color:red">Redraw with first transition duration of 500ms</p>
</div>
<svg style="width:500px;height:150px;margin-top:15px;">
    
</svg>

<p>Transition 0: <span id="t0"></span></p>
<p>Transition 1: <span id="t1"></span></p>
```

Comment: If you're going to have a transition with 0 duration, you may as well just set the attribute to the end value directly.  Why bother with a transition at all in this case?

Comment: Because it can make transitions easier to manage. Suppose a user can trigger transitions on an element. They will often trigger a new transition on an already transitioning element. What if you need to start the newly triggered transition from a specific color or opacity? Using a 0 duration transition is an easy way to cancel the already running transition and specify the new start color.

Comment: It might e an edge case bug, you'd have to trace through the d3 code to see what's going on. A better way to achieve your goal, as described in your comment, is to use styleTween to control the starting conditions for your entering transition.